# What is using Oracle database space? ("ORA-12953: ... exceeds the maximum allowed database size")

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle11gr2

I just have materialized view (small no of rows) in my oracle database and nothing but my database is compalining :

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB

select sum(size_in_mb) from 
(
SELECT owner,
       segment_name,
       segment_type,
       sum(bytes)/1024/1024 size_in_mb
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS','SYSTEM')
 GROUP BY owner, 
          segment_name,
          segment_type
 ORDER BY SUM(bytes)/1024/1024
 );
```

How do I find how much space which is using in oracle?

Comment: There is a DBA-specific stack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume from the error that you are using the express edition of the database.

```
SELECT owner,
       segment_name,
       segment_type,
       sum(bytes)/1024/1024 size_in_mb
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS','SYSTEM')
 GROUP BY owner, 
          segment_name,
          segment_type
 ORDER BY SUM(bytes)/1024/1024
```

will show you the size of the objects owned by users other than `SYS` and `SYSTEM` ordered by their size in MB.

Comment: @Kitex - That is the total?  Or the size of the largest object?

Comment: @Kitex - Did you create any objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schemas?

Comment: I created object in my own schema!

Answer (score 3):

There are several DBA views, which look at several different aspects of "space":

```
* dba_free_space

* dba_data_files

* dba_tablespaces
```

Here are several simple - and useful - scripts:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_free_space_script.htm

I would definitely look at these scripts:

- http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:285415955510